# Can I assign 2 different types to typescript interfaces?

Tags: typescript

I have following interface structure to store travelers.

```
interface Person: {
    age: number,
    name: string
}

interface TravelersDirectory {
    [country: string]: Person[]
}
example:
    travelersDirectory = {
        'India': [
            {
                age: 30,
                name 'X'
            },
            {
                age: 35,
                name 'Y'
            },
        ]
    }
```

With the new change I am going to decouple persons from the travelers directory
to Persons and references will be stored in Travelers directory. The new interface will be :

```
interface Persons extends Array<Person>
```

But due to the business requirement travelersDirectory can keep either index (to Persons) or Person object

example:

```
    const persons = [
            {
                age: 30,
                name 'X'
            },
            {
                age: 35,
                name 'Y'
            },
        ];

    const travelersDirectory = [
        'India': [
            0,
            {
                age: 35,
                name 'Y'
            },              
        ]
    ]
```

Is this possible? can both types(index and Person object) coexist? I tried to work out by making changes to travelersDirectory interface but it didnt work.
    Attempt 1:

```
    interface TravelersDirectory {
        [country: string]: Person[] | number[]
    }
```

Attempt2 :

```
    interface Persons extends Array<Person | number>

    interface TravelersDirectory {
        [country: string]: Persons
    }
```

How can I do it?

Note: The data structure used is symbolic and I can't redesign it. Only can workaround by playing with the interfaces

Check this link for exact problem https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ypc59j

Comment: Attemp 2 should work

Comment: Attempt 2 works https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-tlexc7

Comment: when i use attempt2, I get error "property age does not exist on type number | Person"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second attempt in the question is a correct way to type this, but it can be simplified to this:

```
interface TravelersDirectory {
  [country: string]: Array<Person | number>;
}
```

After some back-and-forth with OP, I found out the issue was somewhere else, ie this code:

```
function getName(travelersDirectory: TravelersDirectory, country: string, index: number) {
  return travelersDirectory[country][index].name;
}
```

This is because `travelersDictionary[country][index]` can be either a Person or a number, so the property `name` is not guaranteed to exist. To fix this, we need to guard against this and define what should happen if the result of `travelersDictionary[country][index]` is a number. We can do this by saving the result into a variable, and using `typeof` to check if the result is a number before we tell it what will happen if it's a Person.

```
function getName(travelersDirectory: TravelersDirectory, country: string, index: number) {
    const person = travelersDirectory[country][index];
    if (typeof person === "number") {
      // getName was called referencing a number instead of a Person. 
      // Throw Error? Do nothing? Up to you
      throw Error("Can't get name of a number");
    } else {
      // Typescript is smart enough to understand that the variable `person` can't be a number
      // (because we guarded against it in the previous if-expression)
      // so now we can do person.name
      return person.name;
    }
}
```

[Here's a Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jhi5e9) demonstrating this

Answer (score -1):

Based on your requirements the simplest solution is just to refer to the possible values in the TravelersDirectory itself:

```
interface TravelersDirectory {
    [country: string]: Array<Person | number>;
}
```

If you want it to be easier to read you could also use type aliases:

```
type PersonID = number;
type Persons = Array<Person | PersonID>;

interface TravelersDirectory {
    [country: string]: Persons
}
```

I personally think it’s most readable just to use the type alias for the ID and declare the directory as follows:

```
type PersonID = number;

interface TravelersDirectory {
    [country: string]: Array<Person | PersonID>;
}
```

This also allows you to later change the person Id to something else like an object or string instead of a number if needed.

Comment: @ritaj I’m using type aliases here instead of an interface that extends the types as in his examples. This makes the code more readable. Hardly deserves a downvote!

Comment: when I use  Array<Person | number>. I get error "type number is not assignable to type Person"

Comment: @atul Where you’re declaring the TravelersDirectory, it should be const TravelersDirectory = { “india”: [] } - you’ve currently declared it as const TravelersDirectory = [ “india”: [] ]

Comment: I am trying on business project (different from the example). As soon as I made the change, the existing code gives so many errors which i mentioned earlier

Comment: @ShamPooSham travelersDirectory isn't a problem. I fixed it the question!

Comment: @atul You should specify that you're using the `TravelersDirectory` interface when assigning the variable. This works https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-tlexc7

Comment: Thanks @ShamPooSham I edited your example. see the problem. https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ypc59j

Comment: @atul in your latest example your code containing the error assumes that this.travelersDictionary[country][index] is a Person and will have a name property, but your change means it could just be a number, and numbers don’t have a name property. What should your code do in this case?

Comment: exactly that was my original question. I want the person info either as object or a number(it will a reference to other directory). is it possible? The real use case is I get person data from external api I process it and add it to another directory. when I send back the same data I do merge from references.

Comment: @atul If `travelersDirectory[country][index]` is going to be either an object or a number, it means it can be a number. That's why `travelersDirectory[country][index].name` gives an error: it won't work if `travelersDirectory[country][index]` is a number. You need to guard against that case before you can assume it is an object of type Person. See my forked example https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jhi5e9

Comment: Thank@ShamPooSham!  I was looking exactly for this! I would appreciate if you add this comment as new answer. It will be useful for everyone.

Comment: @atul I added an answer